# How can I run babel node from local node_modules

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I am using babel-node in my project. I want to run babel-node. I have installed globally.

Now I can call '`babel-node index.js`' for start.

But I don't want to use a global package. How can I run from node_modeles (in my project)?

I tried `node ./node_modules/.bin/babel ./index.js` but it not working. I am getting an error `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")` - on windows.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to call binaries of installed packages is `npx` (comes with NPM since v5.2).

Try `npx babel-node index.js` or `npx babel index.js`